# Сборка проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, sfml

День добрый! Мне нужно собрать и запустить проект в Visual Studio. Изначально проект создавался в Clion. Использую библиотеку SFML.

При попытке собрать проект VS выдает вот такую ошибку: `LNK1104 cannot open file 'sfml-graphics.lib'`.

Можно ли тут как-то обойтись без создания файлов `*.vscproj` и `*.sln`?

Я сам могу писать в CLion'е, но мне удобнее было бы писать в VS. Важно сохранить совместимость с CLion, потому что другой человек может только в CLion'е работать.

Это CMake проект

Мне надо запустить этот проект под VS. Если это возможно, то прошу объяснить как это сделать.

Вот CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(SimplePlatformer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Uncomment to make a 'Make' verbose
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# Setup for UNIX-like system
if (UNIX)
    message("--|| Using Unix-like OS ||--")

    # Set 3rd party libraries paths
    set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/UNIX-SFML-2.5.1/include")
    set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/UNIX-SFML-2.5.1/lib")
    set(SFML_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/UNIX-SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML")

    # Link all *.so files
    link_directories(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR)

    # Setup for Windows system
elseif(WIN32)
    message("--|| Using Windows OS ||--")

    # Set 3rd party libraries paths
    if(MINGW AND NOT CMAKE_CL_64)
        message(--|| Using MinGW x86 ||--)

        set(SFML_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1-x86/lib/cmake/SFML")
        set(SFML_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1-x86/bin")
        set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1-x86/include")
        set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1-x86/lib")

    elseif(MINGW AND CMAKE_CL_64)
        message(--|| Using MinGW x64 ||--)

        set(SFML_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML")
        set(SFML_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1/bin")
        set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1/include")
        set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/WIN-SFML-2.5.1/lib")

    endif()

    # Copy all *.dll files to compiled project binaries
    file(GLOB SFML_DLLS "${SFML_BINARY_DIR}/*.dll")
    file(COPY ${SFML_DLLS} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

    # GARBAGE -> Remove
    #link_directories(SFML_BINARY_DIR SFML_LIBRARY_DIR)

endif()

include_directories(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR include)
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio)

if(SFML_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "SFML_INCLUDE_DIR: ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message(STATUS "SFML_LIBRARIES: ${SFML_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "SFML_VERSION: ${SFML_VERSION}")
endif()

add_executable(SimplePlatformer SimplePlatformer.cpp src/Game.cpp include/Game.h)
target_link_libraries (SimplePlatformer sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

Comment: если Вы создавали проект в CLion, то с вероятностью 99% это cmake проект. Современная студия умеет их открывать. В любом случае, такой проект можно и с консоли собрать. Но лучше дать чуть больше деталей, что бы Вам более прицельно ответили

Comment: @KoVadim, да, это CMake проект. Ну студия открыла его, нашла ```*.exe``` файл проекта, но при запуске выдает такую ошибку. Ну я вообще хотел дальше его писать в VS, не будешь же каждый раз через консоль его собирать :).

А не можете подсказать, какую еще информацию нужно указать?
На компьютере стоит mingw

Comment: CMake умеет генерировать проекты VS .sln

Comment: @sololev ага. только возникла ошибка не при запуске, а при линковке. А до запуска ещё дело не долшло. Если допустить, что в CLion и консоли все работает, то похоже, что студия использует свой компилятор, а не mingw, а либа, которую не может найти - она просто не для студии, а для mingw. Вот и все. У Вас есть три варианта - продолжать использовать CLion (не самый хороший вариант), использовать студию, но компилить консолькой или все таки перевести на студийные версий либ.

Comment: @KoVadim почему использовать CLion не самый хороший вариант?

Comment: @KoVadim, CLion без проблем все собирает и запускает. Присоединяюсь к вопросу big smoke, почему использовать CLion не самый хороший вариант? Перевести на студийные версии, к сожалению, нет возможности. Если я буду компилить консолькой у меня же не будет возможности использовать дебаггер.

Comment: я в комментарии написал, почему оно не собрается. Почему не самый хороший?  Если бы он был хорош, то вопроса перехода на студию не возникло бы даже. Я работал немного с CLion и пока могу сказать, что это большая тормозная штука. Встроенная консоль работает через раз. Но для тех, кто использует Idea конечно в самый раз.

Comment: Тебе нужно подключить библиотеку которую ты используешь в самой студии .Есть куча видосов на ютуб где найдешь как это сделать

Comment: ТС как раз хочет обойтись без среды Visual Studio и проектов - он пишет "Можно ли тут как-то обойтись без создания файлов *.vscproj и *.sln?"

Comment: @Vanya проблема как раз в том, что подключена библиотека, но не та. Даже если создать солюшн и подключить там ту же библиотеке, что сейчас есть у автора вопроса, это никак не поможет

Comment: @Vanya, но ведь если я подключу библиотеку у себя в VS, то тогда нельзя будет работать с проектом в CLion'e. А мне нужно это возможность сохранить

Comment: вижу кучу бессмысленных обсуждений, по типу зачем и почему, ОСТАНОВИТЕСЬ. в VS можно работать с cmake проектами так же как и в clion вопрос закрыт. 1) как эта библиотека подключена в cmake? 2) Изначально это был только Linux билд, или в clion он тоже собирался под Windows?

Comment: @Arenoros, добавил в вопрос CMakeLists.txt. Вообще должно собираться и под Linux, и под Windows

Comment: @Arenoros к сожалению, студия требует своей версии библиотек. Она *не умеет работать с mingw* библиотеками. То есть, нужно скачать/собрать под студийный компилятор библиотеку и добавить в cmake ещё пару if, что бы выставить пути к правильным версиям. Но это сложно. Легче написать "ОСТАНОВИТЕСЬ":)

Comment: 1) для чего эти пляски с SFML_BINARY_DIR, SFML_INCLUDE_DIR? В find_package можно задать где искать необходимое 2) откуда названия таргетов sfml-* когда в find_package у тебя SFML? Если он нашёл все запрошенные либы то они будут хранится в переменной SFML_LIBRARIES

Comment: @KoVadim, а вот теперь подробнее, на кой ляд использовать прослойку mingw вообще? ок, это имело смысл в году так 2012, когда студия работала криво не было отдельных тулчейнов у vc и т.п, для чего оно в 2020?

Comment: опять же, прочитайте выше то, что Вы назвали "кучу бессмысленных обсуждений" - потому что CLion по дефолту использует его. А потом уже ругайтесь.

Comment: Блоки Setup в начале расчитаны исключительно на работу с MINGW. Скрипт поиска sfml, выполняемый find_package наверняка делает не то, что вам нужно. Более того, пакеты sfml ищутся как опциональные, однако затем их опциональность игнорируется. Ну и cmake не умеет генерировать проекты для студии, пригодные для разработки, а вносимые в них изменения не будут отражаться в cmake.

Answer (score -2):

В `CLion` с недавнего времени есть поддержка `MSVC` помимо `MinGW`, `Cygwin` и `WSL` из коробки. Достаточно настроить Visual Studio toolchain и нажимать зелёную кнопку для запуска как и с `MinGW`.

Пример настройки: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#MSVC

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но мне надо работать в VS с проектом, который был создан в CLion'e. Возможно, я что-то не так понял, но это не ответ на мой вопрос